# How to know how much space is left in a spiffs partition on a ESP8266?

Tags: esp8266, spiffs

I need to know how many bytes are left in the SPIFFS partition on my ESP8266 and report it.
How do I get that info?

Thanks

Comment: https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/latest/filesystem.html#info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this tells you about the blocks that have been marked as deleted but you can look at the free_blocks member in the spiffs_t struct. (There is a delete blocks count too but you could dump all three and that should give you a good idea of what is going on with the flash).

```
  typedef struct spiffs_t { 
  ....
     // current number of free blocks
     u32_t free_blocks;
     // current number of busy pages
     u32_t stats_p_allocated;
     // current number of deleted pages
     u32_t stats_p_deleted;
```

Comment: Thanks.
It works !
But why you repeated this line? u32_t free_blocks;

Comment: Cut and paste error. Thanks for pointing it out. Glad to be of asistance.